# How to upload video to YouTube with VP09 & Opus 251

Tags: youtube

I would like to know how big artists send their videos to YouTube and in what format to have VP09 with OPUS 251 in Audio ? 
I tried a lot of format HD H.264 AVI but Youtube keep my video in mp4 with bad audio quality . 
How can i do to have the same format like professional videos youtube ?

Answer (score 0):

What device are you reading the VP9 and Orbis codec information from? These are hardware limited, so the options may not be available on your device.